# Play Application/octect stream in HTML video tag

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, fetch-api, bloburls

We are trying to play video from a VMS system in HTML, we do have an https videoFileDownload link which gives the file, my plan is to use fetch api to get the video and use blob url to play in  tag. However, the blob data url getting created is of type application/octect stream(which is actually an avi file).
How can I convert this blob url to avi and get it played in video tag/

Comment: You can't play AVI in HTML5 browsers. Nearest way is if the AVI contains a supported codec like H.264 for the video and MP3 or AAC for the audio. In such a case, you would extract the a/v data from AVI into an Array and then re-package into a fragmented MP4 structure for playback in `<video>` tag using MediaSource Extensions...

Comment: This code shows how to save a Blob as a (AVI) file in your downloads folder: |https://gist.github.com/philipstanislaus/c7de1f43b52531001412